# Is there a nice way to control how display templates should render null fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there a way to control how built-in display templates (like decimal, string) should render null fields / empty string? I'd want to show "-" as field value for some and empty line for others.

I know I can check those fields for null in the views, but this seems like a not nice thing to do in hundreds of places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply the [`NullDisplayText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.nulldisplaytext.aspx) property of the [`DisplayFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute to the relevant view model members.

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "-")]   
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Note, the `DisplayFormat` attribute is intended to be used with templated helpers such as `EditorFor` and `DisplayFor` (which it sounds like you are doing).

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own display template and control the behavior from there.

```
@model string

@if(Model == null){
    // your behavior here.
}
else {

}
```